# How to find an event and then react to it in a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js

Suppose you have access to a project and you click something in the UI. It triggers some `$emit('theirevent')`" event lower down in "their" components. How can you do something like this:

```
<my-directive @theirevent="myFun()">...
```

in you own directive? Is their some easy way of seeing the scoping name or whatever it is in chrome dev tools?

Maybe something to do with this? [How listen to all events from one component in VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55199485/how-listen-to-all-events-from-one-component-in-vuejs)

Comment: could you explain that by an example?

Comment: It is an example. Do you mean code that is deployable? No ... that is the point, this is a question a) about chrome dev tools grab an event deep in some vue stack and then b) how to reference that from a higher level component. I don't even know how to prepare the example as I am "on the outside looking in" so to speak and trying to understand how to do something.

Comment: I don't even know yet if this is the right question to ask. The simplest thing is how to react to an event in vue when all I know is how to use dev tools and click things as a starting point.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim not sure if I need to @ you in the comments, should have done so I guess.

Comment: without a real example we couldn't guess the real issue and its solution

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim What do you mean with a "real example"?

Comment: some starter code and explain what do you want to achieve clearly

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Oh I see. The problem is it isn't a code question, it is a I have a huge project, chrome dev tools open, and an event somewhere in the lower level components that I do not want to modify. I want to refer to *that* emitted event in my directive. Is there a way to reference this? 

No code is required for this, it is a knowledge question. The code required is huge and reducing the code required is equivalent to answering my own question.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim and I am not clear on how to post starter stuff for chrome dev tools. It isn't really code and can not be reproduced only described.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I've added a bit in case that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you want - your `<my-directive @theirevent="myFun()">` is not a directive, but a component (OK, it's a component's opening tag).

Here's a directive example:

```
<my-component
  my-directive
  @theirevent="myFun()"
>
  ...
```

More on directives [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html)

But if you would like to know how to handle en event emitted "deep down", then you should use `$listeners`:

```js
Vue.component('GrandParent', {
  methods: {
    handleClicked(paramFromGrandChild) {
      console.log(paramFromGrandChild)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      GrandParent:
      <parent @clicked="handleClicked" />
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('Parent', {
  template: `
    <div>
      Parent:
      <child v-on="$listeners" />
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('Child', {
  template: `
    <div>
      Child:
      <grand-child v-on="$listeners" />
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('GrandChild', {
  template: `
    <div
      @click="$emit('clicked', 'param bubbling up')"
    >
      Click me!
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render(h) {
    return h('GrandParent')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can see that in the snippet above the event handler is set in the `GrandParent`, then the `$listeners` object is passed down to the `GrandChild` - and that emits the event on `click` that the `GrandParent` is expecting (and handling).

Actually this is exactly, what the `$listeners` object is supposed to do:

> To solve this problem, Vue provides a $listeners property containing
> an object of listeners being used on the component.

*Source: [vuejs.org](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components)*

### SMALL TRICKS

1. the `$listeners` is an object that contains all the event listeners that wait for an event "above" the current component.

```js
Vue.component('GrandParent', {
  methods: {
    handleClicked(paramFromGrandChild) {
      console.log('grandparent clicked', paramFromGrandChild)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      GrandParent:
      <parent @grandparent-clicked="handleClicked" />
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('Parent', {
  methods: {
    handleClicked(e) {
      console.log('parent clicked', e)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Parent:
      <child @parent-clicked="handleClicked" v-on="$listeners" />
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('Child', {
  template: `
    <div>
      Child:
      <grand-child v-on="$listeners" />
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('GrandChild', {
  mounted() {
    // just to put out the object
    console.log('GrandChild $listeners', this.$listeners)
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div
        @click="$emit('grandparent-clicked', 'param bubbling up')"
      >
        Click me to trigger event in GrandParent component
      </div>
      <div
        @click="$emit('parent-clicked', 'param bubbling up')"
      >
        Click me to trigger event in Parent component
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render(h) {
    return h('GrandParent')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

2. You can "hijack" a listener

Just redefine the function in the `$listeners` object:

```js
Vue.component('GrandParent', {
  methods: {
    handleClicked(paramFromGrandChild) {
      console.log('grandparent clicked', paramFromGrandChild)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      GrandParent:
      <parent @grandparent-clicked="handleClicked" />
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('Parent', {
  methods: {
    handleClicked(e) {
      console.log('parent clicked', e)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Parent:
      <child @parent-clicked="handleClicked" v-on="$listeners" />
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('Child', {
  methods: {
    handleGrandParentClick(e) {
      // no bubbling!
      console.log('grandparent-clicked "hijacked" by Child', e)
    },
    handleParentClick(e) {
      // this is bubbling!
      console.log('parent-clicked "hijacked" by Child', e)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Child:
      <grand-child @grandparent-clicked:stop="handleGrandParentClick" @parent-clicked="handleParentClick" v-on="$listeners" />
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('GrandChild', {
  mounted() {
    // just to put out the object
    console.log('GrandChild $listeners', this.$listeners)
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div
        @click="$emit('grandparent-clicked', 'param bubbling up')"
      >
        Click me to trigger event in GrandParent component
      </div>
      <div
        @click="$emit('parent-clicked', 'param bubbling up')"
      >
        Click me to trigger event in Parent component
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render(h) {
    return h('GrandParent')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In the snippet above, `Child` also handles the emitted events:

- `grandparent-clicked`: `Child` **stop**s & handles the event (not going up in the hierarchy)
- `parent-clicked`: `Child` handles the click, but "lets it through" to the next up component that handles this event